# AspImage fails to display after url rewriting

Tags: c#, image, url-rewriting, relative-path, binaryfiles

I have the following C# code, setting Image value from database. Images are not displayed, fails to show image. It worked until I made url rewrite.

```
ASPxBinaryImage Icon = (ASPxBinaryImage)e.Item.FindControl("IconImage");
Icon.Value = Convert.FromBase64String(string.IsNullOrEmpty(N.Icon) ? "" : N.Icon);
```

Comment: could you check with Fiddler or something similar what happens with that request ? Because there is a still request, from DevEx help : ASPxBinaryImage uses the Value property to store a byte array, which the DevExpress framework translates into <img src> where src requests a DevExpress-implemented URL to serve the byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

What is the generated  tag for the icon ? It may help you get the error source.

Comment: /mysite/news.aspx?DXCache=6f38bdad-589a-4c00-88d2-3e3288a86235

Comment: Do you handle DXCache value yourself server side ?! I think the component you are using will handle it, right ?

Comment: Found something related to DXCache. DXCache uses session and when it fails to generate an icon for you probably it means that the session data is lost. Have a look at this [How the DX cache is implemented?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q358295.aspx)

Comment: You said you have made url rewrite, yes ?! Can your web app respond to such normal request ?! I mean the src part of the <img/> tag ?! What is your current rewrite form ?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed rules of url rewriting and now it's working.